# iOS 7 UISearchBar customization when it is first responder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I'm trying add background image on my search bar when it going to navigation bar. But if I'm writing something like this:

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchBarBG2.png"]];
```

there is always black color and it look bad at status bar: [image]

The size of my image is 320:64

Comment: You add search bar programmatically?

Comment: no, via interface builder in storyboard

Comment: is dat a searchbar  or search display controller?

Comment: search display controller. i've already get answer. look comments under Sandeep Agrawal asnwer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For iOS7, try doing

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;

[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setBackgroundImage:[self imageWithColor:[UIColor yourColor]] forBarPosition:0 barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: previously I used just `setBackgroundImage` without metrics and position. It's work perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
searchBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@ searchBarBG2.png"];
```

Comment: I've tried it. But it works when search bar is not a first responder.

Comment: if you add above `searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`